# Using PouchDB+CouchDB sync capabilities with a Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

We are thrilled about the new IndexDB API and the different overlays that have been created.

One got our attention for it's sync capabilities : CouchDB on the server and PouchDB for the clients.

It should work very well for webApp that should work by themselfs, but in the real life we often need server-side work.
A simple example : imagine you want to shoot an email when a user change a book's title.

This is a simplified example but we would use Laravel as our back-end framework.

So in the use-case :

- the user change the book's title,
- it's saved on his PouchDB
- it's synced on the CouchDB
- the other clients get the book's title updated in their PouchDB
- ... but how does the Laravel knows the book's title has been updated ?

Is there any events system it should hook on ? Maybe thrue redis ?

And once it's done, if the Laravel update the CouchDB, will it fire a sync for all the clients ?

This is a very open question, please feel free to share other solutions than Couch+Pouch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) ?

[This library](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/socket-pouch) is exactly what you want. Using PouchDB with socket connection it will open a websocket connection with server. And on the backend you will listen on same port for events.

Regarding to use it in laravel, I think you can use [this package](https://github.com/robsonvn/laravel-couchdb) to listen on events.

Have a look at this video *(just to see how sync works)* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jOF23dfvl4

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure to see how i would do this.  The first library is very nice (i'm a bit desapointed that PouchDB use HTTP out of the box), but the second one is to connect Laravel to a CouchDB with Eloquent layer, with is model instanciation, so it's not capable of listening to CouchDB events.  I'm wondering if the solution is to write a CouchDB-compliant API for Laravel...

Comment: I haven't used neither couchDB or PouchDB, but websockets. So I can drive you a way, cant provide full solution. So you have to get to know how to join pieces. You can make it work by tweaking little bit according to your needs. Or may be there's ready made library available who knows.

Comment: We are using websocket as well to sync, Laravel provide quite a good ecosystem on that part, but i don't want to re-invent the wheel. Thanks anyway for you answer :)